# Una persona che vuol subdolamente troncare e sopire si dice …

Tags: adjectives, single-words

Qual è l'attributo per qualificare chi vuole troncare e sopire senza darlo a vedere, in modo subdolamente manipolatorio? "Subdolamente sfuggente", "subdolamente evitante": in una parola? Forse solo "evitante"?

Per chiarire sto pensando ad una situazione in cui l'obiettivo è quello di evitare un argomento, una domanda, al fine di imporre ad esempio un determinato status quo all'interlocutore, impedirgli di considerare le alternative, inibirgli l'opportunità di far emergere i propri punti di vista o di far valere i propri diritti, di relazionarsi alla pari, imponendogli cioè un rapporto di dominanza.

Esempio estremo: un educatore che risponde alle domande di un bambino solo se le risposte sono funzionali a rinforzare nel bambino un'opinione soggettiva dell'educatore stesso, ignorando ed evitando tutto ciò che invece farebbe nascere nel bambino direttamente o indirettamente dubbi o ipotesi alternative. Una vera e propria strategia di manipolazione. Lo stesso può accadere in politica o persino nell'ambito di una comunità scientifica laddove ad esempio vi siano interessi economici a mantenere uno status quo ed evitare il formarsi di opinioni alternative.

È possibile - ma non ne sono certo - che in inglese la parola giusta sia "[devious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/devious)" che suona anche bene perché dà l'idea dell'intento di deviare per ingannare. In italiano?

**@donnadulcinea**, **@DaG**, forse in questo caso potrebbe essere necessario usare più aggettivi insieme: «una persona subdola, evasiva, manipolativa»?

**Aggiornamento tardivo**: tornando su questa domanda a mente fredda, penso proprio che non c'è una parola per qualificare il comportamento descritto sù. Forse si può solo arricchire la descrizione con una lista di parole che ne completino il quadro: un plagiatore, un manipolatore subdolo e passivo, sfuggente ed evasivo ma allo stesso tempo ingannevole e indirettamente coercitivo, insidioso e tendenzioso, capzioso, fraudolento.

Comment: Potresti fare un esempio? “Troncare e sopire” che cosa? Una situazione, una persona, un rapporto...?

Comment: "Devious" è *subdolo*, non direi che sia esattamente quello che pensi.

Comment: Sì, forse per una qualifica così complessa una parafrasi può essere più efficace. Però è intrigante questa indagine nei meandri della nostra lingua, se ci si ponessero più domande come questa, le sfumature che ne caratterizzano la potenza espressiva verrebbero perse con più difficoltà. Aggiungo qualche parola alla mia risposta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Io suggerirei `Evasivo`, anche se non forza quella leggera sfumatura manipolatoria di cui parli.

```
Evasivo: Che tende a non affrontare direttamente un problema, 
una questione: mostrarsi e.; parlare in modo e.
```

Forse `Elusivo` rende meglio l'intenzione di *evitare*, ma direi in maniera più celata che subdola. Non necessariamente manipolatoria.

```
da Elusione: Capacità di evitare, di sottrarsi a qlco. 
con furbizia e abilità || 
e. fiscale, comportamento del contribuente che, approfittando 
della complessità delle norme fiscali, riesce a sottrarsi alla 
tassazione senza cadere nell'illegalità
```

Comment: Passando dall'inglese come hai suggerito ho pensato ad altre parole come: deceitful, circuitous (*ingannevole. illusorio*, sviante), treacherous (*perfido, sleale*, mi piace perché ha a che fare con il raggiro e il sotterfugio che hai evidenziato nell'edit).

Answer (score 3):

In realtà “[subdolo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/subdolo/)” è definito dal Treccani come «Detto di persona che tende a dissimulare le proprie intenzioni e a comportarsi in modo falso e coperto, allo scopo di trarre in inganno e di conseguire un fine nascosto», e quindi sembra abbastanza affine all'intento manipolatore descritto nella domanda.